# In select query include placeholder results where no direct result was found

Tags: mysql

I have a table of race results. Not all competitors enter every single race, but I would like to include a table which shows those races they didn't enter with blanks and a hyphen "-" value in the result column.

So, for example, the competitor "John Smith" did not enter a race in either 2004 or 2005, but I want these events to be printed, even though his name does not appear against the records for those races in the database.

I only want this to happen for Race Series ("srs) and years where he did at least enter one race in that year's series of races. So, he didn't do any races in 2003 so not even a hyphen result is shown.

I have produced this code thus far, but it's not working as intended - it is including both the competitors result AND a hyphen for the events he did compete in.

The below should help explain the type of result structure I seek to achieve:

[image: a busy cat]

I have tried the query shown using a UNION. I think I am (hopefully) missing a small trick.

```
select series as srs, 
year as yr, 
concat(year,series) as yrsrs, 
concat(year,series,round) as yrsrsrd, 
round, 
venue,
result
from races
where competitor = "John Smith"
group by yrsrsrd limit 200
UNION
select series as srs, 
year as yr, 
concat(year,series) as yrsrs, 
concat(year,series,round) as yrsrsrd, 
round, 
venue,
case when competitor <> "John Smith" then "-" else result end
from races
group by yrsrsrd order by 2, 1, 5 limit 200
```

Comment: I think you have the "What I want" and "What I am getting" sections mixed up.  But that aside, it would be easier to see _text_ sample data, and also you don't need to show us so much.  Just enough sample data to get the point of your query across would be fine.

Comment: You need to use a JOIN rather than UNION on this. If we can have specific schemas it would be easier to give you an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the second part of your query, but need to change the calculation of the result.

```
select series as srs, 
year as yr, 
concat(year,series) as yrsrs, 
concat(year,series,round) as yrsrsrd, 
round, 
venue,
coalesce(sum(case when competitor = "John Smith" then result end), "-") as result
from races
group by yrsrsrd 
order by 2, 1, 5
limit 200
```

Now look at this line from inside to outside:

```
coalesce(sum(case when competitor = "John Smith" then result end), "-") as result
```

The CASE expression will return the result only for John Smith. For all other rows in the same group (race) it will be NULL. The SUM function will ignore all NULLs and only keep the result of J.S. If J.S. has not participated in that race, all elements of SUM will be NULL, and so SUM will return NULL. At the end COALESCE will convert NULL to "-".

Comment: Thank you, this works very well. The only issue to resolve now is that although John Smith didn't enter any races in 2003, all of the hyphens for 2003 are showing.

Is it possible to only show the years where John Smith contested at least one event?

Comment: You can use another select with a group by to identify the years where he participated in a race, but I believe this should be part of another question as it's a completly different problem.

Comment: Yes - Change `from races` to `from races natural join (select distinct year from races where competitor = "John Smith") x`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Aside from result, I have another field (not included in the MCVE above) for running club. If I adapt your code for that, it isn't listing John Smith's running club for the events he entered, it's only listing the running club of the first competitor encountered (the winner). John Smith's running club only appears if he finished first. Your example uses coalesce and sum because the example field is numeric - what if the field is non-numeric?

Comment: @AndrewAbbott - Then MAX is usually used: `max(case when competitor = "John Smith" then club end)`. You can also wrap it in coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql COALESCE function:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

This function will help you set a placeholder value. (e.g.: COALESCE(result,'-')

Using a join statement, you could do somthing like that:

```
SELECT 
year,
yrsrs,
yrsrsrd,
round, 
venue,
COALESCE(result,'-') as result
FROM (
    SELECT year as yr, concat(year,series) as yrsrs, concat(year,series,round) as yrsrsrd, round, venue 
    FROM races
    GROUP BY yrsrsrd order by 2, 1, 5 limit 200
) a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT result, concat(year,series,round) as yrsrsrd 
    FROM races 
    WHERE competitor = "John Smith"
) b 
ON a.yrsrsrd = b.yrsrsrd
```

Disclaimer: This SQL statement is untested and might have some issues.